# Get the max value of a property in a collection or return zero when the sequence is empty

Tags: c#, linq

Why the GetOrders() does not return any element I get an InvalidOperationException that there are no elements in the sequence.

```
   int maxNumber = GetOrders().Max(o => o.Number);
```

How can I fix this so I get the integer default value which is 0 when the sequence is empty else I want the max value is the sequence is not empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the overload of [`Enumerable.DefaultIfEmpty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355419.aspx):

```
int maxNumber = GetOrders().DefaultIfEmpty(new Order { Number = 0 }).Max(o => o.Number);
```

If you just want to select the `int` value anyway, this approach is even simpler:

```
int maxNumber = GetOrders().Select(o => o.Number).DefaultIfEmpty(0).Max(o => o);
```

Comment: you nearly have my solution see the comment below Dave Zych. Your code does not work because 'o' is a complex object therefore I can not put 0 into DefaultIfEmpty(..) it does not compile.

Comment: @Elisa: Meanwhile edited my answer to provide a default "empty" `Order`. Although your approach is better when you only want the `int` anyway.

Comment: so the new Order is only used when the GetOrders returns no elements right?

Comment: @Elisa: Yes. Edited my answer to add your approach as well.

Comment: fine Tim now I like the answer as I just need the integer value. Thanks.

Comment: I would argue that using `Any()` or the nullable overload are better than creating a new object and the additional delegate invocation. But we're probably talking nanoseconds here. :)

Comment: @Siege: The advatage is that you keep the query "running". It's easier to modify or chain it with `DefaultIfEmpty`. However, the main disadvantage is not the nanosecond but the limitation that i need to create an instance of an object that might not even has a default construcor or which constructor does "expensive" things when i only want to have a 0. But then the second approach which _preselects_ the `int` is better anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Without using Linq you can do something simple like

```
var myOrders = GetOrders();
int maxNumber = myOrders.Any() ? myOrders.Max(o => o.Number) : 0;
```

Comment: i just got it working: int maxNumber = GetOrders().Select( o => o.Number).DefaultIfEmpty(0).Max(o => o);

Answer (score 1):

Or:

```
int maxNumber = GetOrders().Max( o => (int?) o.Number ) ?? 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Aggregate extension method.

```
var max = elements2.Aggregate(0, (m, o) => Math.Max(m, o.Number));
```

Comment: this is cumbersome... Math.Max

Comment: Math.Max cumbersome when finding a maximum?